# How do I create a new Login using SQL Server PowerShell Provider and/or SMO?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I have a PowerShell script which creates a new SQL Server database.  This is going to be a content database for a SharePoint 2010 implementation.

Once created I need to set the DBO to be my SharePoint farm account and I need to assign permissions to some other service accounts.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this using SMO and the PowerShell Provider for SQL Server?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the db owner is simply enough:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\MyInstance\Databases\MyDatabase> $db = get-item .
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\MyInstance\Databases\MyDatabase> $db.SetOwner('sa')
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\MyInstance\Databases\MyDatabase> $db.alter()
#These two steps aren't necessary, but if you want to see the change
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\MyInstance\Databases\MyDatabase> $db.Refresh()
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\MyInstance\Databases\MyDatabase> $db.Owner
```

Assigning permissions is little tricky and of course there are multiple ways to assign a permissions. It would help if you described what permissions you want to assign (database, object, built-in role, server-level, schema, etc.). Here's how you create a database user and assign object permissions:

```
 $user = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User') 'MyDatabase', 'MyUser'
 $user.Login = 'MyUser'
 $user.DefaultSchema = 'dbo'
 $user.Create()
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\MyInstance\Databases\MyDatabase\tables> $tbl = get-childitem | where {$_.name -eq 'mytable'}
$tbl.Grant('SELECT','myUser')
```

Comment: This is really helpful.  The farm account will need DBO privileges on the content database.  I can probably work out what I need to do from your sample.